# Taylor serie of exponential function is not uniformly convergent on R+

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $E_n(x)=1+x+(x^2/2!)+...+(x^n/n!)$

I'm asked to prove that this function is not uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R^+}$

I really don't know how to start here, if anyone could give me a hint it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/418623/

Comment: You could start with writing out the definition of uniform convergence and writing its negation. Please [edit] the post to include this work when you are done. It will have a positive effect on the reception of your question.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the sequence of functions given by
$$ f_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{x^k}{k!} $$
is uniformly convergent to $e^x$ on $\mathbb{R}^+$, then we have that $f_{n+1}-f_n$ is uniformly convergent to zero by the triangle inequality. However, that cannot happen since
$$ f_{n+1}(x)-f_n(x) = \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} $$
is unbounded on $\mathbb{R}^+$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Sir what if we have bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{R^+}$? I think then given sequence of function will be uniformly convergent. But i am unable to see how there exists an integer $N$ such that $|f_{n+1}(x)-f_{n}(x)| ≤\epsilon$  for all $m,n≥N$. please reply